# Split string based on interval

Tags: java, string, split

I would like to split my strings in JAVA based on a regular interval, not on regex. This is what I have to split:

```
  1 x3.1.105.41                           1                    -10
  2 x4.1.105.41                           0                    -10
  3 x12.1.105.41                          0                    -10
  4 y3.1.105.41.19                        1                      0
  5 y4.1.105.41.21                        0                      0
  6 y1.1.105.41.23                        0                      0
  7 y12.1.105.41.25                       0                      0
```

I would like to seperate each column. Currently, I use the  strLine.spli function

Any help would be great!

Comment: If you know the column length, you can use `substring`.

Comment: Your question doesn't explain what you've done to try and solve the problem; it currently reads like a request for code. Please share your attempted implementation and explain how it fails to meet your requirements.

Comment: why don't you want to use regex?

Comment: @user2920611 If you don't want regex, don't tag with that!

Comment: Per the other commenters, if that's representative of all of your data, that's an ideal case for strline.trim().split("[ \t]+");

Answer (score 2):

You can use `substring`:

```
String myLine = "1 x3.1.105.41                           1                    -10";
String column1 = myLine.substring(0, 2).trim();
String column2 = myLine.substring(2, 20).trim();
...
```

Or just split the lines:

```
String myLine = "1 x3.1.105.41                           1                    -10";
String[] columns = myLine.trim().split("\\s+");
```

which gives you in `columns[0]` your first value, in `columns[1]´ your second and so on.

The second solution looks smarter to me.